# Django QuerySet Error

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a simple module below and I have a field called following in the Person module.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
```

I created 3 accounts called sarah , jim and ben. I managed to get Sarah to follow jim and ben but when I display  who sarah followed , it return a querysets not their object themself . How can I work in reverse to get them into objects themself so I can relate them to my Person module and display the names of the people who sarah are following.

This is the part I don't understand

```
>>> from pet.models import *
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> sarah = User.objects.get(username='Sarah')
>>> jim = User.objects.get(username='Jim')
>>> ben = User.objects.get(username='Ben')
>>> Sarah = Person.objects.get(user=sarah)
>>> Jim = Person.objects.get(user=jim)
>>> Ben = Person.objects.get(user=ben)
>>> Sarah.following.add(Jim,Ben) //setup the many to many relationship
>>> Sarah.save()
>>> Sarah.following.all() // return a queryset of Person objects which john is following.
[<Person: Jim>, <Person: Ben>]
```

I want to return all the user objects that user are following in my template.

@SI Eric

```
>>> Sarah.following.all().values_list('name',flat=True)
[u'Jim', u'Ben']
>>> p =  Sarah.following.all().values_list('name',flat=True)
>>> person = Person.objects.filter(user=p)
>>> print person

class Board(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: @bernie  I posted the unicode too do you get what i'm trying to do?

Comment: Apologies, I misread your post.

Comment: @bernie , it was my apologies . I forgot to display the unicode . :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sarah.following.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
```

would output

```
['Jim', 'Ben']
```

As bernie suggested, you can set the **unicode** function and the default queryset returned will do the same.  In this particular type of instance I prefer to be more explicit with what I'm getting from the objects, but that's just me.

**Edit after question was updated:**

I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do.  You have a queryset of the objects of the people who are following sarah.  If you just want the names, the values list above will work.  If you want to iterate over each individual object then you would do something like this:

```
for person in Sarah.following.all():
    # person is an instance of Person
    # you can access all the properties of the object by accessing person
    print person.name
```

Alternatively, pass the entire queryset to the template by adding it to the context in the view:

```
context['following'] = Sarah.following.all()
```

Then in the template you could do this (for example):

```
<ul>
    {% for person in following %}
        <li>{{ person.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**Edit:** 
Both from within the template and the view code you can access any of the properties of each 'Person' object by just directly referencing them.  So for example if you want to access the properties of the 'User' object that person has a Foreign Key relation to, you would just access it's properties directly, like so:

```
person.user.username
person.user.email
etc...
```

**One last edit:**
To get a queryset of 'User' objects based on the 'following` queryset for a person, you could do this:

```
users = User.objects.filter(pk__in=Sarah.following.all().values_list('user__pk', flat=True)
```

From there you should be able use that filter boards and other objects that reference the User model:

```
boards = Board.objects.filter(user__in=users)
```

Comment: Can I ask , why couldn't I do this way p = Sarah.following.all() . person = Person.objects.filter(user=p)

Comment: If you want to just pass all of them to the template and iterate over them there, you could just pass the entire queryset to the template and use the template tags to iterate over them.  Updating my answer now with that code

Comment: Do you mean accessing the user property of each person?  That would just be person.user, which is a reference to the User object for that person.

Comment: If you look below my question . I added another module called Board . Everyone Person can create a board. If I sarah is following jim and ben . How can I retrieve their boards? The only way I can think of is converting all the people from Sarah.following.all() into User.objects.filter(user) then Board.objects.filter

Comment: Edit: just saw your last comment.  One sec.

Comment: I updated the answer with more information for getting the users associated with the following m2m field and using that elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you my SI Eric . I understand  it now .